# Erro na geração de gráfico no R

Tags: r, lista, gráfico

Olá,

Estou tentando criar um gráfico a partir de uma lista, mas não estou conseguindo.

A parte que faz o download funciona perfeitamente:

```
    # download adj. price data - Asset[1],Asset[2]...
symbols= c("TIET4.SA","BVMF3.SA", "CCRO3.SA","ITUB4.SA","WIZS3.SA")

    Asset = list()
    for (symbol in symbols)
      Asset[[symbol]] = as.zoo(download_data(symbol, start_date, end_date))
```

Quando tento gerar o gráfico com esse código:

```
# Visualiza gráficos da carteira
for(i in 1:length(symbols)){
  plot(Asset[i], main=asset1, col=2, xlab="Período",
       ylab="Preço",type="l")
}
```

Recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

Já vi alguns posts mostrando o erro idêntico, mas não consegui entender, nem reproduzir as respostas que foram dadas. Não sou experiente em R!

Alguém poderia ajudar?

Obrigado,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O objeto `Asset` é uma lista. Para selecionar cada elemento desta lista com inter `i` você deve usar duplo colchetes: `[[ ]]`:

```
# Visualiza gráficos da carteira
for(i in 1:length(symbols)){
      plot(Asset[[i]], main=asset1, col=2, xlab="Período",
      ylab="Preço",type="l")
}
```